# (JS) Load .gif and .gifv in an image element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So I'm making an extension (for personal use) that lets me scroll Reddit compact mode using the arrow keys, and all images are previewed in an element created by the extension. The problem I'm having is playing .gif and .gifv in the image element the extension creates. 
Aren't GIF's supposed to be able to load directly into image elements? Not sure about gifv's. I could let the extension check the end of the source for ".gif" and ".gifv", and then create a video element rather than an image element, but is that necessary?

Perhaps there is something I need to add?
Here is the full code I use for adding the image element:

```
function createElement(source) {
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
var bottomPlacement = h - 58;
bottomPlacement = bottomPlacement * -1;
w = w / 2;
h = h - 102;

var new_el
if (source.includes(".gif")) {
    new_el = document.createElement('video');
    new_el.preload = "auto";
    new_el.autoplay = true;
    new_el.style.width = w + 'px';
} else {
    new_el = document.createElement('img');
}
new_el.setAttribute('src', source);
new_el.setAttribute('id', 'extensionOverlay');
new_el.style.height = h + 'px';
new_el.style.position = 'absolute';
new_el.style.float = 'right';
new_el.style.right = '24px';
new_el.style.zindex = 99;
new_el.style.bottom = bottomPlacement + 'px';
new_el.style.border = "medium solid #0099cc"
var plass = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
plass.insertBefore(new_el, plass.children[1]);
document.getElementById('extensionOverlay').addEventListener('load', function() {
    var imageH = document.getElementById('extensionOverlay').naturalHeight;
    var imageW = document.getElementById('extensionOverlay').naturalWidth;
    var percentAltered = h / imageH;
    var widthOfImage = imageW * percentAltered;
    if (imageW < 200 && imageH < 200) {
        new_el.style.width = ""; new_el.style.height = "300px";
    } else if (widthOfImage > w) {
        new_el.style.height = "";
        new_el.style.width = w + 'px';
    } 
});
}
```

A solution was found. Simply change .gifv to .gif and add as an image...:

```
var new_el
if (source.includes(".gifv")) {
    source = source.replace(".gifv", ".gif");
}
new_el = document.createElement('img');
new_el.setAttribute('src', source);
new_el.setAttribute('id', 'extensionOverlay');
new_el.style.height = h + 'px';
new_el.style.position = 'absolute';
new_el.style.float = 'right';
```

Comment: gifv is a bogus type, the real file is a video, mp4 or webm, so you need to use a `<video>` element.

Comment: Changed my code (see edit), still doesn't show anything

Comment: Well, nothing obvious stands out and guessing isn't the right approach anyway. Debug the code. Set a breakpoint in devtools, and when it triggers inspect the variables, DOM, see what happens when you run the code line by line, check the network requests in the network panel of devtools, and so on.

Comment: So everything works until the eventlistener... It is never triggered, as the gif never loads. No idea why. Have never used the network tab in devtools so might take me some time to figure out

Comment: Try replacing all document.getElementById('extensionOverlay') with `new_el` since it's the same element.

Comment: Solved. See edited post.

Comment: I think it'd be better to use a video element AND replace gifv extension with mp4 or webm as it'll load faster and probably provide a better UX/quality.